# handled tag in spring-camel 3.0 xml is deprecated

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

Facing an issue while migrating from 2.x version to 3.16.0. What is the alternative for `<handled><constant>true</constant></handled>` in camel-spring 3.x versions.

What is the alternative for handled and continue in higher versions?

Comment: Please show your code. At least the part of your code that you want to migrate that causes the issue

Comment: <Docatch> <exception > java. Lang. Throwable</exception > <handled><constant > true</constant></handled>

Comment: Here <handled> seems to be removed from 3.x versions

Comment: I meant in the body of your question not as comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `handled` tag is **not deprecated** as you can see in the class [`OnExceptionDefinition`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/core/camel-core-model/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/model/OnExceptionDefinition.java#L77-L79) corresponding to the model class that is used to generate the XSD schema of the Spring XML DSL and in the [latest XSD schema](https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd).

The equivalent of your code in Spring XML DSL is:

```
<onException>
    <!-- the exception is full qualified names as plain strings -->
    <!-- there can be more just add a 2nd, 3rd exception element (unbounded) -->
    <exception>java. Lang. Throwable</exception>
    <!-- mark this as handled -->
    <handled>
        <constant>true</constant>
    </handled>
    ...
</onException>
```

For more details about error handling using Spring DSL please refer [to the documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/exception-clause.html#_using_handled_with_spring_xml_dsl).

Comment: The code posted here is not the 3.x.  Version. Even the documentation also referring 2.x versions.